# CAN bus ground wiring

Tags: can, ground-loop

I am trying to create a concept for a system containing a 36 V battery, a 12 V battery, an Nvidia Jetson AGX Xavier, a CAN transceiver and two motor controllers.

I am struggling to make the correct wiring for the CAN bus. As far as I know, I am supposed to connect the GND of both motor controllers together to create a common ground for the CAN bus. But on the other hand, I don't want to connect them together in order to avoid making a ground loop between both motor controllers and the 36 V battery supplying them.

I thought about using an isolated CAN transceiver, but in my opinion it wouldn't solve the ground loop problem.

Can anyone help me?

[image: block diagram of system]

[image: CAN bus specification]

Comment: * Both MCs (Motor controllers) and the transceiver have a 120Ohm resistor. Is it a problem since it is 3 resistors in a CAN bus instead of two?

Answer (score 1):

You're OK to ground the 12V and 36V battery together. Just don't form a loop. No CAN isolation is required.

As mentioned elsewhere, a common ground isn't actually always required by CAN.

Comment: Can you provide a link to each of the hardware items that gives technical information as asked for by Justme 7//3/21. Places like azon are sales and do not support the devices with schematics etc. I see a distinct possibility things will not go the way you want.

Comment: I know this thread is quite old and it may not now be relevant, but I'm not quite sure what you mean by this comment.

Comment: There are a variety of CAN (example) transceiver chips by many different manufacturers, they are not all the same. These as other devices are placed on PCB and sold many times as a CAN bus interface or whatever. They are definitely not the same and without the proper information the question cannot properly be answered. I will not spend the time researching the many varieties and then guess which one. You usually get what you pay for and documentation is one of the important items, azon, aliexpress and others do not supply that and sell cheaper. I answer questions on several forums no time.

Comment: "a common ground isn't actually always required by CAN" correction: the correct statement is "CAN often works without common ground". But in no way it means that common ground is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Isolated CAN PHYs (transceivers) do solve the problem, because the bus ground reference is only used for the CAN bus side of the transceiver chip, and the MCU side of the chip has a separate logic ground. As the grounds are isolated, there will be no current flowing between them.

And yes, CAN bus must be terminated only at both ends of the bus, so only two terminations must be present.

Comment: So let me see if I understood. A ground loop between both motor controllers and the battery ist not a problem. So the best approach would be to use an isolated can transceiver and connect its ground with both motor controllers (and the ground of both motor controllers with each other). Please confirm if that’s true. And about the 120Ohm resistor, would it matter changing the position of the transceiver with one of the controllers and removing the transceiver resistor?

Comment: The motor controller might already have isolated ground for the CAN bus. If you can, post more info of the motor controller.

Comment: The motor controller ist not isolated.

Comment: OK, as long as the motor controllers that are not isolated connect to same battery, they share the same common reference via the battery negative wiring. Although that is high current, the CAN bus can tolerate some noise and common mode interference. So CAN bus common wire only needs one connection to the motor controllers. But it would still help if you provided info about make/model/datasheet/manual of the motor controller.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant upload the datasheet, but i added a picute of the can communication part of the datasheet where it says no galvanic isolation. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's lay out your schematics a little bit different:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi3jdF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**So, not only you don't have a ground loop (two parallel wires connecting same net), you don't even have a single common ground.**

Just connect two grounds with one wire and you will be fine.

And yes, you need two termination resistors at the ends of the CAN bus. If your motor controllers have those and transceiver does not, then the obvious solution would be to place transceiver in the middle. If all three have termination resistors you need to remove one. The breakout boards for CAN transceivers usually have a jumper for disconnecting the resistor.

Having said that, note that the device placement "in the middle" and termination resistors placement "at the ends" only make sense with relatively long bus. CAN bus can tolerate short stubs just fine, and if you have 20cm stub and 10cm bus then all this talk about termination goes out the window.

In fact, if all your devices are within 20-30cm from each other you can use a single 60 Ohm resistor anywhere on the "bus" and be just fine. I am not suggesting doing this, of course, only saying that it will work.